# How add second line as informative in mat-select?

Tags: angular-material

How add the ability to display the second line as informative (not for select) in mat-select?

`"@angular/material": "^11.0.3"`

```
let Bank = [
  {
    name: 'Bank A', id: 'A',
    branch: [
      {
        name: 'France', id: '1'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bank B', id: 'B',
    branch: [
      {
        name: 'Italy', id: '1'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular HTML and CSS inside your `mat-option` to display it the way you want, here is a very basic example:

```
<mat-option [value]="value">
    <div class="name">{{ value.name }}</div>
    <div class="branch-name">{{ value.branch[0].name }}</div>
</mat-option>
```